# My os cannot read files from my desktop in python

Tags: python, image

This is the code

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

ROWS = 64
COLS = 64
CHANNELS = 3

TRAIN_DIR = 'Train_data/'
TEST_DIR = 'Test_data/'

train_images = [TRAIN_DIR+i for i in os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)]
test_images = [TEST_DIR+i for i in os.listdir(TEST_DIR)]

print(len(test_images))
```

When I run it, it yields that the os cannot find

```
'Train_data/'
```

I have problems to install os packages, I do not know if that is the reason why python does not read the files.

I do not know what else I can do

Answer (score 0):

Try a different folder like downloads etc

The problem might be that by default apps can’t access macOS folders like documents, desktop, etc without permission.

To give the permissions to terminal, go to security settings and enable full disk access for terminal

Comment: I tried to modify the permissions on my cmd but I am not able to find the right command so that my os.win can process the file